# How do I add a rabbit to a number in Python?

Tags: python, magic-methods

I can add a number to a Rabbit class, but not the other way around:

```
class Rabbit:

    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def __add__(self, rabbit):
        if isinstance(rabbit, int):
            return self.age + rabbit
        else:
            return self.age + rabbit.age

print(Rabbit(10) + 5)
print(5 + Rabbit(10))
```

The last line returns:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Rabbit'
```

That's because in the first print expression (which works) `Rabbit.__add__` is called underground, while in the second expression `int.__add__` is called and that `int.__add__` method doesn't work with rabbits. What's the best way to make this work? I want to be able to add ints to rabbits and rabbits to ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation about [`Emulating numeric types`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) and here's what you need :

- The method `__add__` is when the left instance if from the class, here you handle the right instance which can be from the class or other
- The method `__radd__` is when the right instance is not from the class but the left one is, you're cas here

You need

```
def __radd__(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return self.age + value
    print("Other type", type(value)) # handle non-int as you want
```

Giving

```
print(Rabbit(10) + 5)         # add 15
print(Rabbit(10) + Rabbit(5)) # add 15
print(5 + Rabbit(10))         # radd 15
print(5.2 + Rabbit(10))       # radd 'Other type float'
```